# webRTC datachannel's onopen event is not firing even with twilio TURN server

Tags: javascript, twilio, webrtc, p2p, turn

I am using twilio TURN server for webRTC peer connecting two browsers located on different sides of the world, still the connection does not open.
Log shows the local and remote descriptions are set on both sides. Audio/video tracks are also pushed and received, but the "onopen" method on either of the data channels are not firing. Below is the code extract.

create offer code

```
async createOffer(){
    this.initiated = true
    this.conn = new RTCPeerConnection(this.servers);
    if (this.conn){
      this.conn.ontrack = e => {
        e.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {

          this.calleeStream?.addTrack(track);
          this.logs.push('received track:' + track.label);
        })
      }
      if (this.callerStream)
          {
          const s = this.callerStream;
          this.callerStream.getTracks().forEach(track =>
            {
              this.conn?.addTrack(track,s);
              this.logs.push('pushed track:' + track.label);
            });
          }
    }

    this.channel = this.conn.createDataChannel('channelX');
    this.channel.onmessage = e => this.logs.push('received =>'+ e.data);
    this.channel.onopen = e => {
      this.logs.push('connection OPENED!!!');
      this.enabletestmessage = true;
    };

    this.conn.onicecandidate = async e=> {
      if (e.candidate===null && !this.iceCandiSent){
      this.iceCandiSent = true;
      this.logs.push('new ICE candidate received- reprinting SDP'+JSON.stringify(this.conn?.localDescription));
      await this.dataService.createOffer(this.data.callerid,this.data.calleeid,JSON.stringify(this.conn?.localDescription));
      this.logs.push('offer set in db');
      this.logs.push('waiting for answer...');
    }

  }
    const offer = await this.conn.createOffer();
    await this.conn?.setLocalDescription(offer);

    this.logs.push('local description (offer) set');

  }
```

create answer code

```
async createAnswer(offerSDP:string){
    this.initiated = true;
    this.conn = new RTCPeerConnection(this.servers);
    if (this.conn)
            {
              this.conn.ontrack = e => {
                e.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
                  this.callerStream?.addTrack(track);
                  this.logs.push('received track:' + track.label);
                })
              }
              if (this.calleeStream)
              {
                const s = this.calleeStream;
                this.calleeStream.getTracks().forEach(track =>
                  {
                    this.conn?.addTrack(track,s);
                    this.logs.push('pushed track:' + track.label);
                  });
              }
            }

      await this.conn.setRemoteDescription(JSON.parse(offerSDP));
      this.logs.push('remote description (offer) set');

      this.conn.onicecandidate = async e => {
      if (e.candidate === null && !this.iceCandiSent){
      this.iceCandiSent=true;
      this.logs.push('new ICE candidate received- reprinting SDP'+JSON.stringify(this.conn?.localDescription));
      await this.dataService.updateAnswer(this.data.callerid,this.data.calleeid,JSON.stringify(this.conn?.localDescription));
      this.logs.push('answer set in db');
      }
    }
    this.conn.ondatachannel = e => {

      this.channel = e.channel;
      this.channel.onmessage = e => this.logs.push('received =>'+ e.data);
      this.channel.onopen = e => {
        this.logs.push('connection RECEIVED!!!');
        this.enabletestmessage = true;

    };

    }

    const answer = await this.conn.createAnswer();
    await this.conn.setLocalDescription(answer);
    this.logs.push('local description (answer) set');
}
```

server side code for retrieving ice servers from Twillio

```
const twilio = require('twilio');    
const client = twilio(<MY ACCOUNT SID>,<MY AUTH TOKEN>);
const result = await client.tokens.create();
return result.iceServers; //this is set to this.servers in the code above
```

Everything works when I run on two browser windows in my local machine. However even afer implementing TURN they dont work between browsers in Nepal and USA. The onopen event handlers on data channel does notfire even though local and remote descriptions are set on both sides. What am I missing ?
NOTE: signalling is done inside the onicecandidate event handler ( the line that calls dataService createOffer/updateAnswer methods)

Comment: in such cases you typically want to inspect chrome://webrtc-internals and see if ice candidates with type relay are generated and added on both sides.

Comment: webrtc-internals log is only showing typ host candidates. However when I test the TURN server in trickle ice testing site "https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/", i see relay candidate as well ( along with some 701 errors).   Also Should I update signalling SDP every time an ice candidate is received ? Or Can I just gather all ice candidates until icecandidate is null and then update the latest local description set as offer / answer ?   Please help !

Comment: in that case you'll want to check the credentials you are passing to the peerconnection are in the correct format. The candidates must reach the other side, how so is up to you. See https://webrtchacks.com/trickle-ice/ for details.

Comment: Thank you! I had specified TURN servers in wrong format in RTCPeerConnection constructor. new RTCPeerConnection(this.servers) corrected to new RTCPeerConnection ({iceServers:this.servers}) !